# If $G = C_{25}\times C_{45}\times C_{48}\times C_{150}$, How many subgroups of order $5$ does $G$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Suppose that $G = C_{25}\times C_{45}\times C_{48}\times C_{150}$, where $C_n$ denotes a cyclic group of order $n$.

How many subgroups of order $5$ does $G$ have?

I've been trying to understand this in terms of the generators of each cyclic group. We know, for example, that if $C_{45}=<c>$, that the subgroups of $C_{45}$ are $<c^3>,<c^9>,<c^5>,<c>,$ and $<1>$, so there is one subgroup of order 5.

Then we see that $C_{25},C_{45},$ and $C_{150}$ all have one subgroup of order $5$. What does that tell us about the number of subgroups of the product?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already asked, about this same group, [how many elements of order 5 it has](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109215/if-g-c-25-times-c-45-times-c-48-times-c-150-where-c-n-denotes-a-c?rq=1).  In particular, embedded in [Mark Fischler's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2110527/173) we find the answer, 124.

Now, any element of order 5 generates a subgroup of order 5.  But the elements $g, g^2, g^3, g^4$ will all generate the same subgroup.  So the number of subgroups is $124/4 = 31$.